# Data submit with ajax get result but not contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, contacts

I have a online quiz by *jQuery*, I want once the user submit it, to send the results with the contact information's of the users to the moderator.

I make it work, sending the results information correctly, the problem is it doesn't send the user information.

I've been playing around with different solution's, I can manage or to have the user information or the results of the quiz, but not both at the same time !

Here is the "contact form":

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="form">

<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Email</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

<label>Message</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

<input id="button" type="submit" value="Send" class="btnShowResult">
```

Here is the *jQuery* part about the ajax to send the data result of the quiz, the div #resultKeeper being the result I want to receive

```
$(function() {
  $('#form').on('submit',function(e) { e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
              url:'submit.php',
              type:'POST',
              data:{'results':$('#resultKeeper').html(),'subject':'Subject of your e-mail'},
              success:function() {
$('#responseMessage').html()
              }
        });
        return false;

  });
});
```

here is my PHP

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$results = $_POST['results'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message \n Results: \n $results";
$recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "my subject";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Your email has been send, thank you";
?>
```

If in the Jquery I change the

```
$(function() {
  $('#form').on('submit',function(e)
```

by #button instead of #form, I receive the informations from the contact form, but not anymore from the results.

Also by keepin the #form, I receive the result of the quiz, and few value as the form content, but not the informations from the placeholder !, here is what I receive by email:

```
"
From:
 Message:
 Results:
 <div> Question 1 is true</div><div> Question 2 is false\</div><div> Question 3 is true\</div>\<div> Question 4 is false\</div>\<div> Question 5 is false\</div>\<div class=\"totalScore\">\<br>Your total score is 2 / 5\</div>\<div class=\"totalScore\">\<br>CONGRATULATION, YOUR LEVEL IS A1.1\</div
"
```

As we can see I have the From: and Message: appearing, but not the proper name and message that the user are writing ..  .

Any help will be adorable !!

Here is the allcode of JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ccwJJ/

Comment: What does the `z` in `ajaz` stand for? Also, it's spelled `quiz` (1 z)

Comment: Unelss you're just not showing the full show, there's **NO** element with an id of `resultKeeper` in your html, so you're trying to retrieve `.html()` from an element which does not exist

Comment: Hi, I put all in this JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ccwJJ/  thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not receive your form values in your php file when you make an ajax request, you have to explictly send them in the ajax request.

Consider below form

```
 <form action="submit.php">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>  
 </form>
```

**Case 1** Normal way

When you submit the form normally, say hitting enter or on click you would receive the form values implicitly in your php file as `$_POST['email]` variable

```
 <?php $email = $_POST['email'] ; // valid ?>
```

**Case 2** Ajax way

When you submit the form using ajax, You do not receive the form values implicitly in your php file since your `ajax` request does not know about your form elements, You have to send the values explicitly in the ajax request.

```
  $.post('submit.php',function(result){

          $('#responseMessage').html(result);
    });

   <?php $email = $_POST['email'] // error ?>  
   why? because you have not set the post variable email
```

Then how to do it?

```
   var uemail = $("#email").val(); // get the email 
   // Set email and send it through ajax   
   $.post('submit.php',email:uemail,function(result){

          $('#responseMessage').html(result);
    });

   <?php $email = $_POST['email'] // works perfect ?>
```

So now change your form to this

```
 <form action="submit.php" method="POST" id="quesForm">
     <label>Name</label>
     <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Type Here">
     <label>Email</label>
     <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">
     <label>Message</label>
     <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
     <input id="button" type="submit" value="Send" class="btnShowResult">
 </form>
```

Notice I have changed `name='name'` to `name='username'`and I suggest you to change `id=form` to some other name say `id=quesForm`. I have seen some browsers does not seem to work as expected when you use tags  as id names and attributes as attribute values like you have done `name=name` and `id=form`

I suggest you to use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`, It simplifies the things for you when you really require `$.post`

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
   $('#quesForm').on('submit',function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // I am fetching the form values you could get them by other selectors too
    var uname = $("input[name=username]").val(); 
    var uemail = $("input[name=email]").val();
    var msg = $("textarea").val()
    $.post('submit.php',{username:uname,email:uemail,message:msg,results:$('#resultKeeper').html(),subject:'Subject of your e-mail'},function(result){
          // result variable contains your response text
          // I guess you trying to update your response 
         // notice I have used html(result) as you have just used html()
          $('#responseMessage').html(result);
    });
      // you dont require `return false`
      // you have already did it using e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

**php**

```
<?php $name = $_POST['username'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $message = $_POST['message'];
       $results = $_POST['results'];
       $results = strip_tags($results); // add this to remove html tags and all
       $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message \n Results: \n $results";
       $recipient = "thibault.rolando@gmail.com";
       $subject = "my subject";
       $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
       mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
       echo "Your email has been send, thank you";
 ?>
```

To remove html tags in php you have function named `strip_tags();`

Comment: Thank you so much, it work perfectly !!! It makes more sens, glad to learn about it !!

Comment: I've a last question, I receive the result perfectly, only thing is we can see some html code on it, it appear exactly like that Results:
 <div> Question 1 is true</div><div> Question 2 is false</div><div> Question 3 is true</div><div> Question 4 is false</div><div> Question 5 is false</div><div class=\"totalScore\"><br>Your total score is 2 / 5</div><div class=\"totalScore\"><br>CONGRATULATION, YOUR LEVEL IS A1.1</div>

Any way to make the <div class>,etc disappear into the email ??

thanks so much !!

Comment: gonna sound stupid, but how do i accept it ? i'm new on thiss website . . .

Comment: one more thing . ..  When I submit, I don't have the success message from my submit.php file appearing . . . do you knwo how to fix this by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the form data, plus your results string.

Try the following:

```
$(function() {


  $('#form').on('submit',function(e) { e.preventDefault();
        //grab the form data into array
        var formData = $('#form').serializeArray();
        //add your result and subject
        formData.push({ results:$('#resultKeeper').html(), subject:'Subject of your e-mail'});
        $.ajax({
              url:'submit.php',
              type:'POST',
              data:formData,
              success:function() {
                  $('#responseMessage').html()
              }
    });
    return false;
```

});

Comment: I try to edit your answer just for improve formating but cant able because to character limit any way plz edit

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use following way for getting form input values:

```
var data = $('#yourformid').serielize();
```

You will get the data in serielize format and put it on ajax data param.